# Some variable replace from table

Tags: php, mysql, database, api

```
function getApiUrl($mobile, $sender, $message)
{
    $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM sms_api WHERE status='true' and api_id='1' ");
    $row = mysql_fetch_object($query);
    $apiy = $row->url;
    $result = $apiy;
    return $result;
}
```

Suppose Return url = mydomain.com/page?userid=xxxx&pass=xxxx&mob=&sender=&message=

after call this url php called full Return Url

But We Need  = Php code Format / Replace this  and set ".$mobile."

Comment: you need to format your code properly so it's easy to read, and then give us some more information - what does sms_api table look like, then make it more clear what you're actually looking for?  What do you want to return, what are you actually returning, what is actually in the database....

Comment: Completely unclear. Please rephrase everything and show what you want to return exactly with a proper example

Answer (score -1):

function getApiUrl($mobile, $sender, $message)
{
    $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM sms_api WHERE status='true' and api_id='1' ");
    $row = mysql_fetch_object($query);
    $apiy = $row->url;
    $mobile = $apiy;
   getApiUrl($mobile, $sender, $message);
}